# css properties inheritance for font-family not working the way I expected

Tags: fonts, css

I have a web page that I am trying to add a list of links to so that they look like tabs. This is working for all the main pages but the new link list I want to add is in a different section.

The working list is in

```
 <body class="shadowbox">
  <div class="full">
   <div class="banner">
    <div class="tab-header">
```

with several sub-divs to create the various tabs & filler.

Inspecting the element shows that it is getting the font-family from "banner". Even if I put the font-family in "tab-header", it still comes from "banner"

The new list is in another part of the page

```
<body class="shadowbox">
 <div class="full">
  <div class="main">
   <div class="centre">
    <div class="about shadowbox">
     <div class="tab-header">
```

with several sub-divs to create the various tabs and filler.

Inspecting the element shows that it is getting the font-family from "main a". Again, putting font-family in "tab-header" or anywhere else doesn't change that.

Since the font-family is only used for link text, I tried creating a "tab-header a" css definition. That replaces the "banner" definition in the first set of tabs, but the second still comes from "main a".

The relevant css sections are:

```
.main a {
  font-family: serif;
  color: rgb(36,64,143);
  padding-left:  5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.tab-header a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

I can get the correct font family by setting the style in the link itself. I cannot do it by assigning the link a class (i.e.

```
<a style="font-family: sans-serif" ...
```

works but

```
<a class="tab-link" ...
```

doesn't).

This happens in both Firefox and Chromium so there must be something wrong with my understanding of how css works. I had thought that the deeper nested css values would replace the more global ones.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You write that this doesn't work: `<a class="tab-link"` But the CSS rule you defined is for `.tab-header a`

First of all - apart from these two having a completely different names - your CSS selector `.tab-header a` isn't a class, but a combination of a class and a tag, the tag element being a child (or descendant) of the element with that class.

So you have to define a class, like `.my_tabheader1` (not `.my_tabheader1 a {..}`) with the desired settings, and apply that to your `a` tag: `<a class="my_tabheader1" ... >`...